# How to display the variable result as table in email body or console screen?

Tags: powershell

The below script to get the logon users and send as email was working great but only on the console output only.

I am trying to get the result as a table so the result in the console and the email body will be like:

```
Server, ConnectionType, User, ID, State
PRDSVR16, rdp-tcp#44, SVC-SQL, 4, Active
PRDSVR10, rdp-tcp#27, Admin.domain, 6, Disc
SVR25-VM,console,domain.admin,8,Active
```

Open in new window

This is the script:

```
$Today = Get-Date -Format 'F'
$SessionList = "`n`nRDP Session List - " + $Today + "`n`n"
$CurrentSN = 0

# Get a list of servers from Active Directory
write-progress -activity "Getting list of servers from Active Directory" -status "... please wait ..."

$Servers = (Get-ADComputer -Filter { Enabled -eq $True -and OperatingSystem -like "*Server*" } -Properties OperatingSystem -SearchBase "OU=Data Center,DC=Company,DC=com") |
                Where-Object { Test-Connection $_.Name -Count 1 -Quiet } |
                Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

$NumberOfServers = $Servers.Count

# Iterate through the retrieved list to check RDP sessions on each machine
ForEach ($Server in $Servers)
{
    Write-Host "Processing $Server ..." -ForegroundColor Yellow
    Write-progress -activity "Checking RDP Sessions" -status "Querying $Server" -percentcomplete (($CurrentSN / $NumberOfServers) * 100)
    
    try
    {
        $SessionList += qwinsta /server:$Server |
        Select-Object -Skip 1 |
        % {
            [PSCustomObject] @{
                Type = $_.Substring(1, 18).Trim()
                User = $_.Substring(19, 20).Trim()
                ID   = $_.Substring(41, 5).Trim()
                State = $_.Substring(48, 6).Trim()
            }
        } |
        ? { $_.Type -notin 'console', 'services', 'rdp-tcp' -and $_.User -ne $null -and $_.User -ne 65536 } |
        % {
            "`n$Server logged in by $($_.User) on $($_.Type), session id $($_.ID) $($_.state)"
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        $SessionList += "`n Unable to query " + $Server
        write-host "Unable to query $Server! `n $($Error[0].Exception)" -foregroundcolor Red
    }
    
    $CurrentSN++
}

# Send the output the screen.
$SessionList + "`n`n"

$sendMailArgs = @{
    From = "$env:USERNAME@$env:userdnsdomain"
    To   = 'SOC@domain.com'
    SmtpServer = 'SMTP.domain.com'
    Priority = 'High'
    Body = $SessionList | Select-Object @{ N = 'Server'; E = { $Server } },
                                        @{ N = 'User'; E = { $_.User } },
                                        @{ N = 'LogonType'; E = { $_.Type } },
                                        @{ N = 'ID'; E = { $_.ID } },
                                        @{ N = 'State'; E = { $_.State } }
    Subject = "$($SessionList.Count) Logged On users from $($NumberOfServers) online servers as at $($Today)"
}

Send-MailMessage @sendMailArgs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rendering collected information in different places is way easier if you keep strict separation between *data* and *presentation* (or *formatting*) of said data.

For the `$SessionList` for example, that means doing *less* than what you're currently trying to do inside the loop:

```
$ErrorList = @()
$SessionList = foreach($server in $servers){
    try{
        qwinsta /server:$Server |Select-Object -Skip 1 |ForEach-Object {
            [PSCustomObject] @{
                Server = $server
                Type   = $_.Substring(1, 18).Trim()
                User   = $_.Substring(19, 20).Trim()
                ID     = $_.Substring(41, 5).Trim()
                State  = $_.Substring(48, 6).Trim()
            }
        } |Where-Object { $_.Type -notin 'console', 'services', 'rdp-tcp' -and $_.User -ne $null -and $_.User -ne 65536 } 
    }
    catch{
        $ErrorList += [pscustomobject]@{
            Server = $server
            ErrorRecord = $_
        }
    }
}
```

Notice how I *don't* construct any strings - I just create the custom objects, filter them - and then leave them as-is.

Now it becomes much easier to format the data as desired for different output media:

```
# For console output, simply pipe to Format-Table
$SessionList |Format-Table
if($ErrorList.Count -gt 0){
    Write-Warning "The following servers had errors, please inspect"
    $ErrorList |Format-Table
}

# For email output we can use `ConvertTo-Html`
$Body = $SessionList |ConvertTo-Html -As Table -Fragment
if($ErrorList.Count -gt 0){
  $ErrorTable = $ErrorList |ConvertTo-Html -As Table -Fragment
  $Body = $Body,$ErrorTable -join '<br />'
}

$sendMailArgs = @{
    # ...
    Body = ConvertTo-Html -Body $Body -Title "Session list"
    BodyAsHtml = $true
    # ...
}
```

Comment: Hi @mathias, many thanks for the assistance in showing the [PSCustomObject] @{}, now it works great. I appreciate your assistance in this matter.

Answer (score 1):

I got something the same,
a variable in powershell, what must have individual lines in a email.

the simple way i used here is split it and use the foreach like this
so my `$userfiles` contains many files (table)

```
$mailbody += " -------------------------------------------------------------------"
$mailbody += " `n"
foreach ($file in $userfiles) {
$mailcontent = $file.nlocatie.ToString()
$mailbody += " $mailcontent `n"
$mailbody += " `n"
}
$mailbody += " --------------------------------------------------------------------"
```